# Bike stops Suddenly after 2 to 3 Km

Tags: engine, gasoline, royal-enfield, petcock

I have a Royal Enfield 350 Classic,15000km and 4 years old.
These days I am facing a problem ,it stops after a few kms. I was on highway and it stopped so I visited a mechanic he said there is water in your petrol tank ,he cleaned petrol tank as well as carburettor.After few days again same problem, now this time I visited authorize service centre of Royal Enfield , they are saying there is a lot of rust in petrol tank and rust in your petrol on off switch ,so they changed the switch and cleaned the petrol tank as well. .But after taking my bike from the showroom again same problem.I don't now why it occur ? now this time showroom guys saying the there is some problem in your engine so it is cutting fuel supply
Can someone please suggest me what could be the reason and what should i do?

Comment: Have the carburetor cleaned as that may be the issue, then purchase your fuel from a different, quality, supplier.

Comment: yes sir ,the road side Mechanic and showroom guys both had clean the carburetor and I also change the petrol ,last time I I fill petrol from shell extra premium petrol .   still problem ..?? Engine proble.????

Comment: soo after concern with showroom engineer  , he says engine oil is leakage through towards to spark plug.

Comment: Your gas tank breather hole may be plugged. Try riding with the gas cap open a little and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens again, check spark plug has spark.

Comment: sir , right now the Bike is in Showroom and its not starting, may be there is no current in spark plug because of oil leakage.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj I'm not sure how the oil leakage would stop the current in the spark plug. It could be some issue in the ignition coil, in the spark plug itself, or maybe wiring.