# Royal Enfield Thunderbird shutting down on acceleration?

Tags: starting, enfield-bullet

I own Royal Enfield Thunderbird 350. It's getting on in one kick, and will be on as it is untill I don't off it, but as I touch accelerator it will be off.

One other issue(not sure if its related), if I don't start bike for 2-3 days, then it will take lot of time to start, probably 40-50 kicks.

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/41982/10976 and https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27593/10976 and https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/57735/10976

Comment: @SolarMike these answers seems similar but not exact. Thanks.

Comment: The point is they cover all the things you need to consider...

Comment: yea we can assume for consideration,  but in all the references bike was running, and that time only they faced the issue. In my case, bike is standing, and it's not starting.

Comment: You state it runs... unless you have mis-stated what you meant... ie "getting on in one kick” ...

Comment: yes, engine gets on in one kick,  but bike is not running, it's on stand.

Comment: Engine can be running when on the stand or not...

Comment: If you know, what is the condition of your battery, air filter and spark plug.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when some amount of water entered by Fuel Tank due to which the bike was getting started but turned off as soon as i revved it. I took it to the mechanic and he removed the fuel tank then cleaned and dried it. After that i haven't faced the issue.

Also a tip for starting your bike in winter which I usually do, I turn off the kill switch and then kick the bike for 2-3 times. Then I turn off all the switches(headlamps, indicators etc.), turn on the kill switch and then retry kicking. I mostly get it started in the very first kick only.

Happy and safe riding.